# Checking if panels contain something

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, panel

```
private void PBoxJigsaw1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender != null && sender.GetType() == typeof(PictureBox))
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                PictureBox answer = (PictureBox)sender;

                if (answer.Location.X < pnlJigsaw5.Location.X && answer.Location.Y > pnlJigsaw5.Location.Y)
                {
                    if (answer.Location.X + answer.Width > pnlJigsaw5.Location.X)
                    {
                        if ((answer.Location.X + answer.Width) < pnlJigsaw5.Location.X + pnlJigsaw5.Width)
                        {
                            answer.Location = pnlJigsaw5.Location;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (answer.Location.X < pnlJigsaw1.Location.X && answer.Location.Y > pnlJigsaw1.Location.Y)
                {
                    if (answer.Location.X + answer.Width > pnlJigsaw1.Location.X)
                    {
                        if ((answer.Location.X + answer.Width) < pnlJigsaw1.Location.X + pnlJigsaw1.Width)
                        {
                            answer.Location = pnlJigsaw1.Location;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I have created a jigsaw on c# where the user drags pictureBoxs into panels to create an image. I was wondering if it is possible to check if a panel contains something as at the minute numerous pictureBoxs can go into one panel and it can seem like they disappear, although they are just going behind each other. I am just wanting to make it that only only one pictureBox can be in a panel at one time. Thanks

Comment: It seems that you don't actually add anything on your panels. You're just setting picturebox on top of the panel with this line: `answer.Location = pnlJigsaw1.Location;` Consider adding picturebox to the panel with `pnlJigsaw1.Controls.Add(answer)`

Answer (score 5):

You could check whether the `panel` you are dropping the `pictureBox` on contains any `controls`

```
if(panel.Controls.Count > 0)
{
  // Panel contains items inside
  // Ignore Panel
}
```

---

EDIT1:
Did you try placing this code at the top of the event? Like this

```
private void PBoxJigsaw1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(panel.Controls.Count > 0) 
    {
        return; // Panel already contains a control, stop executing the code
    }

    if (sender != null && sender.GetType() == typeof(PictureBox))
    {
        ....
```

Does this make the picturebox disappear?

Comment: i tried including that but where I put it just made the pictureBox disappear